# Typescript String.format does not exist

Tags: typescript, string-interpolation

I have a string const where I have to replace two words, like this:

```
public static readonly MY_STRING: string = 'page={0}&id={1}';
```

0 and 1 have to be replaced with other strings. I have read about String.format in different answers, where they suggest to supply an implementation like this:

```
if (!String.prototype.format) {
  String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
      return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
        ? args[number]
        : match
      ;
    });
  };
}
```

but when I do `String.format` it tells me

```
Property 'format' does not exist on type 'String'
```

What is the proper way to use String interpolation/substitution in this case? With format I'd do something like this:

```
 MY_STRING.format(page, id)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice) to modify native prototypes like `String`.  Since there's no standard or agreed-upon `format()` method for strings in JavaScript, adding your own could lead to unexpected behavior in any code that runs in the same runtime.  Your implementation even checks for an existing `String.prototype.format` first, which means if someone gets there first with a different implementation, then *you* could be the one with unexpected behavior.

There's absolutely nothing wrong with just having a `stringFormat` function sitting around that you use, like this:

```
function stringFormat(template: string, ...args: any[]) {
    return template.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
        return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
            ? args[number]
            : match
            ;
    });
};

const myString: string = 'page={0}&id={1}';
const formattedWithFormat = stringFormat(myString, 123, 456);
console.log(formattedWithFormat); // page=123&id=456
```

---

Also, JavaScript has [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which provide essentially the same functionality:

```
const myTemplate = (page: number, id: number) => `page=${page}&id=${id}`;
const formattedWithTemplate = myTemplate(123, 456);
console.log(formattedWithTemplate); // page=123&id=456
```

---

If you are intent on modifying the prototype of `String` and the previous warnings didn't dissuade you, then you could use the [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) or [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) approach to allow TypeScript to recognize that you expect `string` values to have a `format()` method:

```
/*  here be dragons  */
interface String {
    format(...args: any[]): string;
}
String.prototype.format = function (...args) { return stringFormat(String(this), ...args) };
console.log(myString.format(123, 789)); // page=123&id=789
```

but hopefully you will use one of the other solutions.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZygJxmA5gMTmgWwEMoAKKAUwIAcAbEigLhXUywBpEA6HotLZMyJgAngG0AugEpEAbwBQiJYjQUoINEko16lLqrpEIFUgHpZpADoATANRSAvqY6JQkWAkSliUCAAtOMBACACMKNBkFZWiVNQ0tEWoKOGBEPgExINDwiUQAQgBeRABycGsKYEwKa2LFGPqAfjT+ZEzgsLQJOvro5h9-bp6lAG5BhylRh2HEeXkIBFREAhEAZVZsZlQMbEQi4uoiLAoC2QAGBwAyGGsTgEYHYtH5sEXgfB9KawB1GCg-PEIJF2LG2uHeJG8q3WLluACYAMycAAsAFYAGwTOYLOC0ChcWhwLCkN6AqCfH5-AE+CaIUymRAHI4FOHwq43VFo2bPRbLAAqVEMlGBpEZTEQWQ6nGuzAl4RkBQAfIgAAaigoAElkosu1w1smuDmVTwWUFc4LJ1Qpfn5OgYwL5At0JhZyPRmO5OLxBKJJI+lt+1sdDBpdIZh2OLLZBQ5s1MACpEIBeDcAkDuIPzhCiIMKIaxoQ4LJOAJh3EHHTPJMJQ0MAjJm1qC5INfRCeFx0oI0qJJFJNtDJvI62wuNQ0HAoKPEnim6aim5oPAkKQW23IrF1JoQWwqRCB9hyH4YMgpJwly0ZFMsS9PfjCZCd1guFPSC7EAB2AAcAE4pCH6WrI7r3w-eQgA)

Comment: Thank you! First solution you proposed works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can augment the declaration of string from the base library:

```
declare global {
    interface String {
        format(...args: []): string
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=2&pln=2&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwLACgAmwDGAbAQymDgHM8IAjAvRDOBuASwDsZgoAzAnEgZRhRWpOukbi4naAFsCMABQA6ZUVIBnAFxwA2gF0AlFrWDh9RmnQWMTTnHkBCAUJalFYKBBieAnmGCKpKFkYfVFxJ2E3Dy8YX39A4LgAXkkAVxYcGCYIFjtQhDMJOAA3IjhVNWTyqFJU6WA2NQBuQoliGFSoXJgACyY1RWIwQl55AHoEeQAdTABqfWQx0gAaNIysnLtgnB7VljrKDnzWooZ2zu64iFsK7X3pQ6hdOHsUgHJ07E5WYEw3k9O4gA-NV1HcDhxdADAQwtNsetCYS0xKdkPpkeJkMjkEA)

Note: If not in a module the `declare global` is not necessary, you can just move the `interface String {...}`to the top level ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIDKU6QOboDeo6p6CA9nALZJQAUAdM0nHgM4Bc6A2gLoBKbuxz5QAX1BTwCdPQCE2XBDyMADnApQtATzUxGlGnQFESZJfnWbtUPQaO0o6ALzkArhBRQwFCHNNiEDIQ9AA3VnRWDlcotndqGGh2AG5zUPQ4GCh3OH8oAAswdkYstQAbVBh6AHpCegAdABMAagFxGrwAGg8vHz85JxQCnogEgCN4QPSMsiycvPQ7fQpZaPYeMepJuD50eTcAck8mmARIGCbDmdnQgH44jk2J+D4b27JuIYL3j-Q04KzcQCAEhcQA8RAA))